# Set Lightmaps with index using Texture2DArray for GPU Instanced Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to get GPU Instancing to work with lightmaps I am completely new to shader programming so I'm really struggling with this.
I referred to this link in order to use lightmaps [GPU Instancing + Lightmaps](https://www.xuanyusong.com/archives/4640)

And this [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/6uueox/gpu_instancing_texture2darray/) here showed me how to use multiple textures with Texture2DArray

By using these two links I came up with a shader code as follows

```
Shader "Unlit/TestShader"
{
Properties
{
    _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Textures("Textures", 2DArray) = "" {}
    _Index("Texture Array Index", Range(0,4)) = 0
    _LightmapST("_LightmapST",Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
    _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
}
SubShader{
    Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile_instancing
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;
        fixed4 _Color;

        struct appdata
        {
            float3 pos : POSITION;
            float3 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
            float3 uv1 : TEXCOORD1;
            UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
            float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD1;
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
        };

        struct SurfaceOutputStandard
        {
            fixed3 Albedo;
        };

        UNITY_DECLARE_TEX2DARRAY(_Textures);

        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(fixed4, _LightmapST)
        UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(int, _Index)
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)
        
        v2f vert(appdata IN)
        {
            v2f o;
            UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(IN);
            UNITY_TRANSFER_INSTANCE_ID(IN, o);

            o.uv0 = TRANSFORM_TEX(IN.uv0, _MainTex);

            fixed4 l = UNITY_ACCESS_INSTANCED_PROP(Props, _LightmapST);
            o.uv1 = IN.uv1.xy * l.xy + l.zw;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.pos);
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col;
            col.rgb = DecodeLightmap(UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(_Textures, float3(IN.uv1.xy, UNITY_ACCESS_INSTANCED_PROP(Props, _Index))) * _Color);
            return col;
        }

        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

The Material properties of each mesh type (Which in my case is a shopping rack), is set through the following code

```
        public MaterialPropertyBlock block;
        
        public void GenerateMaterialProperty (Texture2D lightmapTexture, List<Vector4> lightmapOffset, int lightmapIndex)
        {
            block = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
            block.SetColor("_Color", subMeshColor);
            block.SetVectorArray("_LightmapST", lightmapOffset.ToArray());
            block.SetFloat("_Index", lightmapIndex);
        }
```

The code used for GPU Instancing is as follows

```
    for (int i = 0; i < racks.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rackDetails[racks[i].rackID].subMeshes.Length; j++)
        {
            Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced(rackDetails[racks[i].rackID].rackMesh, j, rackMaterial, racks[i].locations.ToArray(), racks[i].locations.Count, rackDetails[racks[i].rackID].subMeshes[j].block, UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.Off, false, 0, Camera.main);
        }
    }
```

But with all this code The lightmaps are only properly applied to one of the mesh instances
[lightmap output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqL6l.jpg)

I fail to fully understand the problem Any help on how to get lighmaps to work with GPU instancing will be appreciated
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I used "Graphics.DrawMesinstancedIndirect" function and combined the shader with provided in this [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedIndirect.html) here I was able to get lightmap textures to work with instanced models